# Linear constrains Z and D in MARSS package

Tags: r, state, kalman-filter

Recently, I need to establish a MARSS model such as:
`y_t = c + beta * d1_t + alpha * x_t + v_t; x_t = x_(t-1) + w_t`
then I try in R and I meet the problem:

```
Error in optim(pars, negloglike, method = "BFGS") : 
  objective function in optim evaluates to length 0 not 1
```

My benchmark model:
`y_t = c + beta * d1_t + alpha * d2_t + alpha * x_t + v_t; x_t = x_(t-1) + w_t`
My code:

```
y = rnorm(10)
x = matrix(0, 3, 10)
x[1:2, ] = matrix(rnorm(20), 2, 10)
x[3, ]= 1
x0 = matrix(0.1, 1, 1)
V0 = matrix(0.01, 1, 1)
B = matrix(1, 1, 1)
U = A = 'zero'
# pars to be estimated
pars = c(beta=0.5, alpha=0.5, c=0.5, q=1)
# calculate loglike
negloglike = function(pars){
  Q = matrix(list('q'), 1, 1)
  R = matrix(1, 1, 1)
  Z = matrix(list(pars['alpha']), 1, 1)
  D = matrix(list(pars['beta'], pars['alpha'], pars['c']), 1, 3)
  model.list = list(B=B, U=U, Q=Q, Z=Z, A=A, D=D, d=x, R=R, x0=x0, V0=V0)
  -1 * MARSS(y, model=model.list, control=list(
    maxit=200,conv.test.slope.tol=0.1,abstol=0.1),method='kem', silent=TRUE)$loglik
}
optim(pars, negloglike, method = 'BFGS')
```

but it denoted:

```
Error in optim(pars, negloglike, method = "BFGS") : 
  objective function in optim evaluates to length 0 not 1
```

I need help, Thanks!

Comment: It's `$logLik`, not `$loglik`. Try running inside the function first before using it in optim :)

Comment: Thanks for your good idea! May I ask another question？I want to increase a restriction:The 'alpha' and 'beta' in The parameters subject to 'alpha + beta=1', I try to change The Optimal method from 'optim' to 'constrOptim', but I don't know The gratitude function, so The initial value of parameters influence a lot.What should I do ?

Comment: Can you set `grad=NULL` and use the default Nelder-Mead optimiser? If it's really sensitive to the starting points, you could loop and try different combinations e.g. (0.1, 0.9), (0.2, 0.8), (0.3, 0.7), ... etc. if it doesn't take too long to run the model 10 times and see which output has the best loglik